# Why props alone are being used in called React function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was learning React and I came to a point which created confusion. Everywhere I was using props while writing Function components.

I always use `props.profile` and it works fine. But in one code component, I had to write 
`const profiles=props;` and it worked fine.

I tried using `const profiles=props.profile`; and also I tried using inside `return` in 'Card' function component

`{props.profile.avatar_url}` but both of them failed

Below is my code which works fine

```
const Card=(props)=>{
  const profiles=props; //This I dont understand
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src={profiles.avatar_url} width="75px" alt="profile pic"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>{profiles.name}</div>
        <div>{profiles.company}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const CardList=(props)=>{
  return(
    <div>
      {testDataArr.map(profile=><Card {...profile}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why I can't use `const profiles=props.profile`?

What are the other ways to achieve the correct result?

Comment: `props.avatar_url` works fine? then just do `const Card=(profiles)=>{`

Comment: @Federkun You mean const `Card=({profile})=>{` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `testDataArr` might be this,

```
testDataArr = [{avatar_url:"",name:"",company:""},{avatar_url:"",name:"",company:""},{avatar_url:"",name:"",company:""}]
```

Now when you do this,

```
{testDataArr.map(profile=><Card {...profile}/>)}
```

here `profile = {avatar_url:"",name:"",company:""}`,

and when you do,

```
<Card {...profile}/>
```

is equivalent to,

```
<Card avatar_url="" name="" company=""/>
```

In child component, when you do this,

```
const profiles=props;
```

here `props = {avatar_url:"",name:"",company:""}`

So you can access it's values,

```
props.avatar_url

props.name

props.company
```

But when you do this,

```
const profiles=props.profile
```

**`profile` key is not present in `{avatar_url:"",name:"",company:""}` object and it fails.**

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is the issue, the props object does not contain a profile attribute, but IT IS the profile attribute. Becouse you are spreading the profile variable when you render the Card element (in the CardList), you basically are writing:

```
<Card avatarUrl={profile.avatarUrl} comapny={profile.comany} />
```

Instead, you should do

```
<Card profile={profile} />
```

and then in your Card component access the data this way

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const profile = props.profile
}
```

or even simpler

```
const Card = ({profile}) => {
  return <div>{profile.comany}</div>
}
```